# Why does modifying an unrelated variable cause a change in my linked list?

Tags: c, arrays, methods, linked-list

I am attempting to make my linked list work at the simplest level. I want to add a new node (variable wordNode) to the linked list I have defined (wordList). In my main C file I have created a new list (createWordList) and added a node to it with the word "Hello" from the inputLine.

The problem is that when I attempt to print the word of the head of my list, **any changes made to the input line are printed instead.** For example, instead of "Hello" being printed here, "Go" is printed. I can't understand how this is possible, because the input line is completely unlinked to the hash table; the word "Go" shouldn't be impacting the values inside the hash table right? Below is the code for the main function.

```
struct wordList* hashTable;
hashTable = createWordList();

char inputLine [20];

// set input line to Hello
strcpy (inputLine, "Hello");

// add Hello as the head node to the linked list
addWordNode (hashTable, inputLine);

// set input line to Go
strcpy (inputLine, "Go");

// print the head of the list. this is currently printing Go, instead of Hello.
if (hashTable->head != NULL) {
  printf ("%s\n", i, hashTable->head->word);
}
```

Here is the code for the createWordList() function:

```
struct wordList* createWordList() {
  struct wordList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct wordList));
  list->head = NULL;
  return list;
}
```

And for the addWordNode() function:

```
void addWordNode(struct wordList *list, char * word) {
  struct wordNode* currentNode;
  struct wordNode* newNode = malloc (sizeof(struct wordNode));
  newNode -> word = word;
  newNode -> docFrequency = 1;
  newNode -> next = NULL;

  // I've only included the first case, because that is what is setting the head value.

  if (list->head == NULL) {
    list->head = newNode;
    return;
  }
```

I'm sorry to be asking for straight debugging, but I've been at this for hours. Is there a **larger behavior of strings or string operations** that I don't understand? Or is there a simple error in there?

Comment: "because the input line is completely unlinked to the hash table"? Quite the opposite, in your `addWordNode` function you link the new node directly to the local `inputLine` array, pointer to which you passed to `addWordNode` function from the outside. That "unlinking" is something you forgot to do.

Comment: Thank you! This is getting clearer, but arrays must be passed as pointers in C so how do you get around this? I tried doing a `strcpy` into a new array in the `addWordNode` function but that didn't help. What is the standard practice if you have to pass an array that will continue to be modified?

Comment: "I tried doing a strcpy into a new array in the addWordNode function but that didn't help". That's a reasonable thing to do and should work if done correctly. Specifically, if you have allocated the memory correctly. So please show exactly what you did.

Comment: You need to use `strdup()` or `malloc(strlen(word) + 1)` followed by `strcpy()` to assign to `newNode->word` in `addWordNode()`.  Also note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never have spaces around them. As it stands, you copy the same pointer into `newNode->word` each time, so all the words point at whatever data that pointer points at.  Remember to free the extra allocated space as you free up elements of your list.  And beware memory allocation failures.

Comment: It all works now!! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"because the input line is completely unlinked to the hash table"? Quite the opposite, in your `addWordNode` function you link the new node directly to the local `inputLine` array, pointer to which you passed to `addWordNode` function from the outside. That "unlinking" is something you forgot to do.
                    – AnT